# Est-ce que « Il s’emporte à la moindre insatisfaction » se dit?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation

Au sens de: Il s’emporte pour peu qu’on ne le satisfasse.

J’avais aussi à l’idée d’écrire « Il s’emporte de colère dès qu’il n’est pas satisfait. »

À votre avis, quelle serait la meilleure construction?

N’hésitez pas à me donner d’autres propositions si votre jugement esthétique vous interpelle.

Merci!

Comment: Bien qu'assez formelle, la formule en titre me parait tout à fait convenable

Comment: ***Il est vite vénère dès qu'il est pas joye.***  ;-) Ce serait bien d'indiquer dans la question le registre de langue attendu…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bien que la phrase en titre convienne, j'aurais plutôt utilisé :

- *Il s'emporte à la moindre contrariété.*
- *Il s'emporte pour un rien.* (plus courant, mais plus vague)

Comment: Il est "soupe-au-lait" : http://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/16497/etre-soupe-au-lait/ ; il est susceptible, colérique, un rien le fâche.